# Loop for updating prices in an API

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I am importing data from a spreadsheet to a dataframe that contains product information that I need to send in a put request through an API to update prices in an e-commerce, but I have a problem I don't know how to create the loop to iterate all the dataframe correctly.

This is an example:

| Product_Id | Variations_id | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id001 | v0101 | 100 |
| id002 | v0201 | 120 |
| id003 | v0301 | 110 |
| id003 | v0302 | 115 |
| id004 | v0401 | 120 |
| id005 |  | 130 |

Approach 1:

If the product doesn’t have variations:

```
url = "some_api_url" + str(product_id)

body = {‘price’: int(price)}

token = token_key

payload = json.dumps(body)
headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Approach 2:

If the product has one variation:

```
url = "some_api_url" + str(product_id)
body = {
    "variations": [{
    "id": str(variation_id),
    "price": int(price)
    }
   ]   
   }


token = token_key

payload = json.dumps(body)
headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Approach 3:

If the `product_id` has two or more variations append the `variations_id` and the price in the same body:

```
url = "some_api_url" + str(product_id)


body =  {
    "variations": [{
                    "id": str(variations_id_1),
                    "price": int(price_1)
            },
            {
                    "id": str(variations_id_2),
                    "price": int(price_2)
            },
            {
                    "id": str(variations_id_3),
                    "price": int(price_3)
            }
         ]
    }

token = token_key

payload = json.dumps(body)
headers = {
 'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Note: if a product has more than one variation and I omit any of them, those omitted variations are eliminated, and as a result, they are products that will disappear from the e-commerce.

How can I iterate all the dataframe that each of the `product_id` passes its respective `variations_id` and price in the JSON body and if the next `product_id` is the same add the `variations_id` and price to the current body like the `product_id` "id003" with two variations?

Comment: Group by product_id and iterate over the groups?

Comment: Does the api require a put with all product id's or can you do multiple puts, one for each product id?

Comment: one put for each product_id

Answer (score 1):

> How can I iterate all the dataframe that each of the product_id passing its respective variations_id and price in the JSON body

- Use `DataFrame.iterrows` and build one large *body*. As long as you make a dictionary from each row you won't miss any variations. Might be a good idea to  sort by product id first.
- or use `DataFrame.groupby`, group by product ID; iterate over the groups and build a body for each group and *put* that.

---

[Splitting an object into groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)